# JavaScript null check - value is null, but check still fails?

Tags: javascript

```
if (this.meta.addText !== 'null')
{
    console.log("hi");
}
```

So when `this.meta.addText` is null, this check still goes into the `if` and prints `hi`.

What am I missing?

Comment: No need to downvote this. Op is clearly just confused about the javascript operators, Antonpug I think you should look here to learn more about JS: http://autotelicum.github.com/Smooth-CoffeeScript/literate/js-intro.html#operators

Comment: Is this your actual code? Are you really wanting to test the string `'null'`? Does your actual code test `null`, but you meant to test `undefined` or `null OR undefined`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'null'` is a `string`.

Change it to `null`.

```
var string1 = null,
    string2 = 'null';

console.log(string1 == string2); // false
console.log(null != 'null'); // true
```

You can see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QVhcH/).

Comment: Try always to use === and !== comparators to avoid implicit type casting. http://oreilly.com/javascript/excerpts/javascript-good-parts/bad-parts.html

Answer (score 2):

Because it's `null`, and **not the string** `'null'`. Try this instead:

```
if (this.meta.addText !== null)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're testing against the string "null", not against the value null.